# Cypress Access Array element API response nested json

Tags: json, automation, cypress

I cannot quite figure out how to access the 0th element in the array as part of the JSON body in order to check the API response.  I have tried various ways and none seem to be correct.

I currently have the following as an example:

I'm guessing it is not difficult but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Thanks!

```
        cy.get('@dogs')
            .its('body')
            .its('breeds[0]')
            .its('names')
            .should('include', {
                count: ('10'),
            });
```

Comment: Can you add a sample json for more clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [its](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/its.html#Arrays). The indexes should be accessed individually with `its`.

Response JSON:

```
{
  "sample": [
    { "names": ["Dummy 1", " Dummy 2"] },
    { "names": ["Dummy 3", " Dummy 4"] },
    { "names": ["Dummy 5", " Dummy 6"] }
  ]
}
```

The last object in the array should be accessed as:

```
// to check a child's length
  cy.get('@sample')
    .its('body') // 'responseBody' in case of latest cypress version
    .its('sample')
    .its('2')
    .its('names')
    .its('length')
    .should('eq', 2);

// To check content
  cy.get('@sample')
    .its('body') // 'responseBody' in case of latest cypress version
    .its('sample')
    .its('2')
    .its('names')
    .its(1)
    .should('include', '6');
```

Screenshot:

[image: test_screenshot1]
[image: test_screenshot2]